# Android - download another app programmatically

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to download apps programmatically? I don't mean to launch Google Play to a certain app. Let's say i have 3 apps, all related but have different functionality. Is it possible to create a 4th app which when you download also downloads the other 3 and serves as a hub for them? If so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep.  I just did this the other day.  Your app will need some permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Write external storage is because you'll have to download and save your APK file somewhere.

Additionally, you'll need to grab the file somehow.  I use Java's `HttpUrlConnection` object to do the actual downloading (you can probably search for a better explanation of how to download a file in an Android app, but it's pretty straightforward).

Once you have your file downloaded, you just start up the package manager and tell it to install.  Unfortunately, the user will be faced with the same dialog as usual for installing an app, and they can choose to decline the installation.  To install without user intervention, you would probably need to connect from your app to ADB and call the package manager that way, although I'm not sure what kind of privileges would be involved there.  If you don't mind the user seeing an install confirmation dialog, then this code will work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/whereever-you-saved-this.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

The FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK prevents crashes on some phones if the APK you're installing overwrites the app you used to launch the Package Manager.

Comment: you did this to download an APK from somewhere other than Google Play, correct?

Comment: At the time you are launching the application manager, it's just an APK.  It doesn't matter where you got it from, whether or not it's signed, etc.  It's just a file on the SD card that the app manager happens to know what to do with.  You could use this to download from the market or from somewhere else, it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can't automatically install apps, this would be pretty risky for users.

You could download a bunch of new APKs, but the user would have to install them by himself by opening the .apks.

You can however also create 1 big app internally, but show it as multiple small apps since you can set multiple Activities as launcher activity. Maybe that's an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option for [Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).  Perhaps that might fit the bill?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in this way also:

Download APKs files from server via web-service and after download install these APK files by using INSTALL_PACKAGES permission.